# Local declaration of `barButtonback` hides instance variable in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am totally new in ios development, I want to add back button in navigation controller , so I found this code from stackoverflow

My code is :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 UIBarButtonItem *barButtonback=[[UIBarbuttonItem alloc] init];
 barButtonback.title=@"back";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=barButtonback;
 }
```

Error : Local declaration of 'barButtonback' hides instance variable

Is there any different solution to add back button in navigation controller or please give solution for this error

Comment: Looks like you declare `UIBarButtonItem *barButtonback` in interface class.
like in .h or .m. so remove that and warning will be gone.

Comment: You have a global variable `barButtonback` in your class. Change the local variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means already U have used or assigned this variable  `barButtonback` in globally or used some where else, so u can do two ways

either

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 barButtonback=[[UIBarbuttonItem alloc] init];
 barButtonback.title=@"back";
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=barButtonback;
}
```

or

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 UIBarButtonItem *barButtonback1=[[UIBarbuttonItem alloc] init];
 barButtonback1.title=@"back";
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=barButtonback1;
   }
```

Try This

```
barButtonback = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"back"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(butBackAction:)];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=barButtonback;

  -(void) butBackAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

//perform your action

   }
```

Comment: Error is gone thank you..but back button is not showing in screen ..please help me

Comment: r u used stroyboard or xib

Comment: No there is not like storyboard or xib , It is Initframe in .m file

Comment: I know my friend , in your project r u using storyboard or xib

Comment: yea..Karthik, I understand your question but,actually I have one existing ios app , and It has nothing like storyboard or .xib file,only .h and .m files are there for particular event..and In this existing app I want to add back button in navigation controller(or action bar in android) ..please plz help me..Thx in advance

Comment: I used your code but at -(void)saveAction:(butBackAction *)sender gives error : Expected a type

Comment: karthik.saral@gmail.com (Skype , GMail, FB, Twitter ) connect anyone friend

Comment: sry sry wait I update my answer friend this is my fault now check